# Return dataframe or vector from a function

Tags: r, function, vector, return-type

I computed the model fits (AIC) from -LL inputs. I used a vectorized function and I want to return a `data.frame` or `vector` of all computed values for further analysis. The function works fine, but if I define an output vector, it doesn't return this vector.

Here's my function:

```
function.aic <- function(k,LL)   {    
    aic <- (2*(LL)) + (2*k)    
    m <-mean(aic)  
    print(m)    
    print(aic)
    aic_vector <- as.data.frame(aic) }
```

Further, it would be great to save this vector in an object with the name of the input variable "LL" to have specific objects for each computation. But I just don't know how to do it, Google didn't really help.

Comment: Seems like you are just missing a return statement?  `return(aic_vector)`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are just missing a return statement. Also, to give named output, you could use `deparse` and `substitute`  to obtain the variable name. You could then create a list, and give the list element the name of your variable. For example:

```
function.aic <- function(k,LL)
{
  aic <- (2*(LL)) + (2*k)
  m <-mean(aic)
  print(m)
  print(aic) 
  aic_vector <- as.data.frame(aic) 

  mylist=list()
  mylist[[deparse(substitute(LL))]] = aic_vector
  return(mylist)
}

input_1 = 10
input_2 = 10

x = function.aic(input_1,input_2)
```

x now is:

```
$input_2
  aic
1  40
```

and so,  `x$input_2` contains your AIC dataframe. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer! I'll now defined a "name" variable in the function input. But the geneal issue (even adding the missing return statement) is, that I don't get an object in my environment. It prints the output, but doesn't saves it.

Comment: Hi Jan, do you assign the output to a variable? i.e. do you call the function as `x <- function.aic()`  or `x = function.aic()` instad of simply `function.aic()`?

Comment: I now do it like 

drift_varying_aic <- function.aic(9,drift_varying_LL)
so i get my object. but if I call the function just like 
function.aic(9,drift_varying_LL), i don't get an object, even if I define it within the function like aic_vector <- aic

Comment: Anything declared within the function itself is not available outside of the function, this is called scoping. For more info on scoping, see for example [here](https://www.programiz.com/r-programming/environment-scope)